# How can I get the panel's children to dynamically reset their Location.Y property?

Tags: c#, winforms, resize, panel, groupbox

I have a panel on a form, with the panel's AutoScroll property set to True.

On that panel I have placed several GroupBox controls, which take up more space than the panel does - thus, the panel sprouts a vertical scroll bar.

One of the panels can change height at runtime if need be (I programmatically set its height based on the amount of text it contains):

```
groupBox1.Height = label1.Height + label1.Top + 10;
```

This works fine if the panel increases in height - the GroupBoxes below it "move down." However, if the panel decreases in height, the GroupBoxes below do not "move up."

I know I can move the groupbox controls that are below upwards programmatically, but I'm thinking there must be a better/less fussy way of doing it than that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the `Panel` with a `FlowLayoutPanel` instead and this will become automatic.

(you might want to turn off the wrapping of the FL-Panel)

Answer (score 1):

Set their docking property to Top.  Then change the Z order of the children to specify their display order.

```
GroupBox1.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
GroupBox2.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
GroupBox3.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

If groupbox1 grows or shrinks the other 2 panels will move to accommodate.

Comment: Either by right-clicking the controls and doing 'Bring to Front', 'Send Backward' etc.  Or you can just go into the designer.cs file and just arrange the order in which they're added to their parent.